# creating a protocol header using python pack

Tags: python, header, protocols, pack

I have developed a python code to implement a protocol header. The protocol starts with 0x2 and ends with 0x3 and anything in between is protocol and its payload. I am creating all the fields and pack them individually and at the end add all the packed fields together to make my packet. I send this message to another host when it connects to me over a socket. The machine that receives it complains that it did not receive the last byte (0x3). However, when I print the message right before I send it, All fields are correct. I wonder if pack is doing something to my packet when it sends it out. I can send you my code if you need to see it, but I thought you might have some ideas about building a protocol header in python. I appreciate any help I can get. Thanks

Comment: `pack` doesn't send your packet out, it just gives you a `bytes` that you have to send yourself, so it can't be doing anything to the packet when it sends, only your other code could be.

Comment: Meanwhile, are you sending this over TCP? If so, are you just assuming that a single `recv` call will get exactly one packet, or are you looping and buffering?

Comment: At any rate, there's obviously something wrong somewhere, and there's no way we can debug that something in code we can't see. But nobody wants to read your entire client and server. Please reduce what you have to a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem, and post that here.

Comment: One last thing: What happens if there's a `0x3` byte in the payload?